# MPI: Best way to coordinate many sends and recieves

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I've been away from parallel programming for a long period of time and I am trying to figure out the best method for coordinating sending large amounts of data between many processors with a complicated dependency structure. For example, I might to send data to/from the following processes:

```c
int process_1_dependencies[] = {2,3,5,6}
int process_2_dependencies[] = {1}
int process_3_dependencies[] = {1,4,5} 
int process_4_dependencies[] = {3,5,6}
int process_5_dependencies[] = {1,3,4,6}
int process_6_dependencies[] = {1,4,5,7}
int process_7_dependencies[] = {6,8}
int process_8_dependencies[] = {7}
```

The obvious, and stupid, way of doing this would be do something like:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < world_size; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < dependency_length; j++)
   {   
      if (i == my_rank)
      {
         mpi_irecv(...,source=dependency[j],)
      }
      else
      {
         if (i == dependency[j])
         {
            mpi_isend(...,dest=dependency[j])
         }
      }
   }
   // blocking stuff?
}
```

I'm not actually sure if this would work once you have 100's of communications going and in anycase, it seems super inefficient. It's at least O(N) and only allows a single process to be receiving at once. A better way would be to use blocking and ensure that independent processes are simultaneously exchanging information. But that becomes quite complicated and requires optimizing which processes are simultaneously sending and receiving.

Am I just completely overthinking this? Is it safe to do something like this (provided that every sending process has a receiving pair):

```c
for(int i = 0; i < dependency_length; i++)
{
   mpi_isend(..., dest=dependency[i], ...)
   mpi_irecv(..., source=dependency[i], ...)
}
//blocking stuff
```

sorry for the lack of focus in the question. I'm away from my computer so I can't really test it out, and in even if it did would I guess I'm not confident that it is saleable and that the buffers would keep working for arbitrary numbers of processes?

Comment: unless you can find an optimal **and** deadlock free way of using blocking operations, you'd rather simply queue non blocking requests and `MPI_Waitall()`. An other option is to use MPI topology and `MPI_Neighbor_alltoall()`. If this is a fit, it would be more elegant but I cannot guarantee the implementation will be more efficient than manually using non blocking operations.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid queueing a large number of messages and to avoid opaque deadlock problems, you can also employ a single call to `MPI_Alltoallv`, where all sends and receives are done for you automatically, and---with crossed fingers--- even hope that you MPI implemetation is able to optimize all communication on its own. The prototype is

```c
MPI_Alltoallv
(
    sendbuf,    // buffer containing all data needed by other ranks in comm
    sendcounts, // number of elements to send to each rank in comm
    sdispls,    // offsets in sendbuf per rank in comm
    sendtype,   // MPI datatype of the sent data
    recvbuf,    // buffer to contain all data needed by this rank
    recvcounts, // number of elements to receive per rank in comm
    rdispls,    // offsets in recvbuf per rank in comm
    recvtype,   // MPI datatype of the received data
    comm        // the communicator
);
```

where `sendcounts` would be directly related to your `process_X_dependencies`; it would contain non-zero values at positions listed by `process_X_dependencies`.